# Can POCL be used in iOS devices

Tags: pocl

I am actually very new to OpenCL and POCL.

Can we use POCL in iOS devices. I see the docs contains the usage details in Android http://portablecl.org/docs/html/using.html#using-pocl-on-android

But I am not able to find it for iOS devices. 
It seems we can use some [private API](https://github.com/linusyang/opencl-test-ios) for using OpenCL in iOS.

Can we use POCL in iOS devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware anyone porting it to iOS, but I'd guess it's not impossible because it already works in MacOS, and iOS even might have a version of LLVM installed on device.